# systemd for git pull when server start up

Tags: git, systemd

my service file as follow:

```
[Unit]
Description=git pull models
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/sched_server_run.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/app/xxx

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=pullformodels.service
```

sched_server_run.sh content is :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/git --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/app/xxx/.git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/app/xxx/  pull
```

I run "systemctl status gitpull.service " the error is :

```
● gitpull.service - git pull models
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gitpull.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-08-19 07:53:45 UTC; 5min ago
  Process: 4493 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/sched_server_run.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4493 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 19 07:53:42 ip-172-31-26-167 systemd[1]: Started git pull models.
Aug 19 07:53:45 ip-172-31-26-167 sched_server_run.sh[4493]: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address
Aug 19 07:53:45 ip-172-31-26-167 systemd[1]: gitpull.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 19 07:53:45 ip-172-31-26-167 systemd[1]: gitpull.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

my question:

how to configure git pull use systemd

Comment: I doubt that `root` has your `git` credentials for github. Did you try to set the `service`'s user? Did you test `sched_server_run.sh` with `uid=0`?

Comment: yes , my all operation  use root ,i run sched_server_run.sh is ok ,but use systemd is error

Comment: Looks like `Requires=network.target` is not enough. 
You network is up, but you are not connected. Try `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` or `network-online.target` or wait yourself `while ! ping www.gitlab.com; do sleep 1; done` or similar.

Comment: I add User=root in [Service] and is ok:    ```[Service]
User=root 
Type=simple
```